# How to make my bootstrap carousel work with ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I got a problem so I came here for some help, I got some pictures that I want to show like a carousel, I got the carousel working when I use stockphotos from the internet, but when I use photos I got in the wwwroot folder, all the pictures just show at the same time, and the carousel doesn't work, my Razor-syntax looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row justify-content-center container-fluid, caros">
    <h1>@Model.car.Model</h1>
</div>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.car.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            var f = 0;
            if (f == 0)
            {
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i" class="active"></li>
            }
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i"></li>

        }

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            @if (Model.car.Images != null)
            {
                @foreach (var i in Model.car.Images)
                {
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="~/Images/Cars/@i.Filename" alt="First slide">                       
                }
            }
        </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't each image need to be in it's own `.carousel-item` container?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I believe your problem starts here

```
var f = 0; <==== PROBLEM
if (f == 0)
{
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i" class="active"></li>
}
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
```

you are setting f = 0 every time in your loop so therefore you are always going to have that as the first image and overlaying on top.

try something like this

```
if (i == 0)
{
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i" class="active"></li>
}
else{
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="@i"></li>
}
```

As I will increment each time and should work as you intend.